# Adding associated elements with Spring Data REST and Restangular

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, restangular, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring data REST named methods for my REST API. Some of exposed resources look like this:

Courses entity:
localhost:8080/data/courses/

Modules entity:
localhost:8080/data/courseModules

Each course can have multiple modules so I also have this:
localhost:8080/data/courses/{courseId}/modules - list of modules that are associated with course.

If I want to add new module I can naturally do this in two steps:

- First add new module (with POST to localhost:8080/data/courseModules)
- Associate newly added module with course (another POST to localhost:8080/data/courses/{courseId}/modules)

Question is:
Is it possible to do it in one step? I'm using Restangular and the way it works would suggest that this should be possible. With Restangular I would do something like this:

```
Restangular.one('courses', {courseId}).all('modules').post(newModule);
```

where newModule is json object.

Restangular than issued POST request to address: localhost:8080/data/courses/{courseId}/modules

This doesn't work hovewer. I'm getting "204 No Content" and no new object is added to my database. I can add new module making POST to this address: localhost:8080/data/courseModules but it would be so much easier if I could just make this request to localhost:8080/data/courses/{courseId}/modules. I expected that Spring Data REST will accept my POST request to localhost:8080/data/courses/{courseId}/modules and than automatically do the following:

1. Add new module
2. Create association of new module with course of id {courseId}

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question YES. Following will be an approach i would like to suggest to you.
Say you have a scenario were

1. Add new course and modules
2. Delete an existing module.

Approach for scenario 1:

Endpoint URL : localhost:8080/data/courses/  HTTP Method : POST
The request body will be a JSON/XML which will have something like:
Course name [Module1, Module 2.....]

Approach for scenario 2:

Endpoint URL : localhost:8080/data/courses//id  HTTP Method : DELETE
The request will contain an id of the module that has to be deleted.
Hope this ansers your question. Please let me know if you have any more question

Comment: Solution for scenario 2 is clear. But when it comes to scenario one, it is not really what I have in mind. What you've suggested means that I would have to extend my backend to expose a service that would handle this. This is possible solution of course but I'm trying to get more advantage of Spring Data REST. Therefore I wondered if it automatically exposes possibility to POST to localhost:8080/data/courses/{courseId}/modules and than it automatically adds module and associates it with course with id 'courseId'.